# Dynamically create UIButton based on response from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder, xcode6

I need to implement a view that require me to create a buttons based on the response from the server.

**Example response:**

```
{
   ...
    "enable_button_1" = 1;
    "enable_button_2" = 1;
    "enable_button_3" = 1;
   ...
}
```

Currently, I try to create the buttons manually using Interface Builder. And each of them are embedded in UIView and put on top of each other. Like so:
[image: Creating button one by one]
They are hidden by default. So, whenever on or more buttons enabled, I will check using `if` conditions and then unhide the view.

**eg. only one button enabled**

[image: one button enabled]

**eg. two button enabled**

[image: two button enabled]

But the thing is by doing so, I would probably miss a few use case and this seems like a bad practices. Is there any way that I could create it dynamically instead of creating multiple buttons in UIViews in Interface Builder?

Comment: If you want to use Interface Builder you will need to add the buttons like you are now to the screen, create an IBOutlet for each button's width, and set the width to 0.0 to "hide" the desired buttons. If you do your constraints right everything will resize for you... That being said if you want to use say a loop to make it more scalable then your going to have to do it in code. If you only have 3 buttons though like above, then Interface Builder will do just fine, but I recommend creating IBOulets for the buttons widths instead of "hiding" them, its a lot more powerful.

Comment: @DBoyer, cool. thanks for the suggestion. It's "hidden" now, but it doesn't resize. I tried set the constraints, but still. Why setting the width to hide the button is better than using `setHidden` though?

Comment: If you set horizontal constraints between the buttons, changing the width will cause the adjacent button to fill the remaining space. If the width is 0.0, then the button will not appear on screen so its "hidden", while the adjacent button expanded to fill the remaining space (this is the power of auto layout).

Comment: @Dboyer, oh, i see. You're talking about autolayout. I thought It was autoresizing. When I change it to autolayout, I can't set the width to 0,0 though. I tried to change the size using `setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)` previously. Mind sharing how you do it? I'm still not that familiar with autolayout. Thanks

Comment: The auto layout system is built on the concept of Auto Layout Constraints, because of that the frame sizes are handled internally by the system all for you (hence "auto layout"). What you are in charge of is telling a view how to resize by setting auto layout constraints. It is these constraints that you may control. If you would like to change a constraint in code then you create an IBOutlet for that constraint (like the button's width) and set the constraint to 0.0 like so: self.buttonWidthConstraint.constant = 0.0;

Comment: So turning on auto layout means that changing frames in code by calling CGRectMake(0,0,0,0) will NOT work. This is why people are so divided on whether or not to use auto layout still. Some people love it and some hate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create buttons programatically and add them to your view. You'd have to calculate the width of the button-frame so that they always fit the view 100%.

For example somehow like this:

```
    //Here you'd have to calculate the correct position of the button you want to add
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.buttonView.frame.size.width, self.buttonView.frame.size.height);
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [button setTitle:@"myButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: He is using Interface Builder which utilizes layout constraints, setting the frame is not possible which elements create via storyboard. You can only change the constraints.